# chown only where needed / speedup chown

Tags: chown

On a folder with millions of files this can take quite a long time:

```
chown someuser -Rf /folder_with_lots_of_files/
```

How can I speed this up if 99.9% of those files already belong to `someuser`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use the `find` command, like:

```
find /folder_with_lots_of_files -not -user someuser -execdir chown someuser {} \+
```

Comment: how is it different from running `chown -R` ? isn't `find` need to read the file owner as well ?

Comment: `chown -R` blindly attempts to update the ownership of every file.  The find approach only issues a `chown` where truly needed.  May be worth trying `xargs` too, so that a single chown process is issued for, say, every 15 files.

Comment: But it'll still have to `stat` each file in the tree and that shouldn't be (?) any cheaper that an attempt at `chown`. I think `find` with `-prune`  (with `-exec ... \+`) might help (if there's a criterion for pruning a subtree that the OP can use).

Comment: Interesting. This does appear faster. Recursively `chown`ing the kernel tree takes me about `200ms` of sys time. The `find` approach takes about `100`.

Comment: `find` has to `stat` each file to traverse the tree (to distinguish directories), and if the number of `chown` calls are relatively small, that will run faster.  It would not run faster if the fraction were *not* small, due to overhead of running the `-exec` to make subprocesses.

Comment: Now I realize chmod has to stat echo node to traverse the tree. That should explain the doubled sys time -- it needs to both `stat` and `chown` and both syscalls should be quick, with the syscall overhead dominating.

Comment: what if we need to change both user and group? eg. `chown user:group`? Can we modify this command to accommodate it?

Comment: yes @PrasannjeetSingh, instead of `chown someuser` above use `chown someuser:group`.